# How to pass instance variable to infowindow Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am creating parking monitoring app, and I am completely new to programming and ruby on rails particularly. I've found a great extension for Gmaps - Gmaps4rails.

I have several markers showing the location and congestion of parkings (Class Place) on the map. User (Class User) should be able to click on marker and in this little pop-up infowindow there should be "follow" button, so the user could stay updated about parking congestion.

Here is my code

Model Relationships

**User**

```
has_many :parking_relationships, :foreign_key => "watcher_id",
                                 :dependent => :destroy
has_many :watching, :through => :parking_relationships, 
                                :source => :watched
```

**Place** (parking)

```
has_many :reverse_parking_relationships, :foreign_key => "watched_id",
                                         :dependent => :destroy,
                                         :class_name => "ParkingRelationship"
has_many :watchers, :through => :reverse_parking_relationships,
                                :source => :watcher
```

**ParkingRelationship**

```
belongs_to :watcher, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :watched, :class_name => "Place"
```

**Places Controller**

```
def index
@user = current_user
@place = Place.find(params[:id])
@places = Place.all
 @json = Place.all.to_gmaps4rails do |place, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/places/watch_form", :locals => {       :object => place})
 end
respond_with @json
```

end

Partial **_watch_form.html.erb**

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
 <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.watching?(@place) %>
   <%= render 'watch' %>
  <% else %>
   <%= render 'unwatch' %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Partial **_watch.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for current_user.parking_relationships.
                      build(:watched_id => @place.id) do |f| %>
 <div><%= f.hidden_field :watched_id %></div>
 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Watch" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Partial  **_unwatch.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for current_user.parking_relationships.find_by_watched_id(@place),
         :html => { :method => :delete } do |f| %>
 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unwatch" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**Database structure**

```
Users name, email, etc
Places Name, address, latitude, longitude, gmaps, congestion
Parking_relationships watched_id, watcher_id
```

This doesn't work. When I click on marker, nothing happen, and "Watch" or "Unwatch" buttons don't apper. I suggest this is because @places in index action of Places controller.

```
UPDATE:
Here's the app on the web
GitRepositary https://github.com/ilyacherevkov/parking_bob
Map http://parking-bob.heroku.com/places
Watchers of the parking http://parking-bob.heroku.com/places/1,2,3 etc/watchers
Users watching parkings http://parking-bob.heroku.com/users/1,2,3 etc/watching
```

Thank you, folks